# Flask-WTF SelectField with CSRF protection enabled

Tags: python, flask, csrf

I'm having a problem when submitting a form containing a dynamically populated SelectField. For some reason when Flask tries to validate the CSRF token it always fails when the SelectField is in the form. When I remove the SelectField from the form, it validates the CSRF token successfully.

Has anyone come across this behavior?

**EDIT**

Form:

```
class AddToReportForm(Form):
    selectReportField = SelectField(u'Reports',choices=[('test1','test')])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initiates a new user form object
        :param args: Python default
        :param kwargs: Python default
        """
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)




    def validate(self,id_list):
        rv = Form.validate(self)

        if not rv:
            print False
            #Check for the CSRF Token, if it's not there abort.
            return False

        print True
        return True
```

Jinja2:

```
<form  method=post name="test">
{{ form.hidden_tag()}}




    {{ form.selectReportField }}
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit()" class="button save">Add to report</a>

</form>
```

Rendering:

```
form = AddToReportForm()
return render_template('random',title='add reports',form=form
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Yea, I'll make a concept :)

Comment: Updated with some code

Comment: Are you sure it's CSRF failing and not some other reasons? The `SelectField.choices` looks little suspicious, isn't it expected to be a list of `(value, label)` tuples, not just strings?

Comment: Yea updated that, in my code it's indeed a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still can't see any connection between SelectField and CSRF. The `validate` method is little suspicious and the extra argument would trip the following testcase, but as it stands this seems to work just fine:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
from flaskext.wtf import Form, SelectField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 's3cr3t'


class AddToReportForm(Form):
    selectReportField = SelectField(u'Reports', choices=[('test1', 'test')])


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = AddToReportForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print 'OK'
    return render_template_string('''\
<form method=post name="test">
{{ form.hidden_tag()}}
{{ form.selectReportField }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
''', form=form)


app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: The problem ended up being a typecast for the id in the database which should have been coerced for the SelectField.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you setting SECRET_KEY? It must be available either in the Form class:

```
class AddToReportForm(Form):
    selectReportField = SelectField(u'Reports',choices=[('test1','test')])
    SECRET_KEY = "myverylongsecretkey"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initiates a new user form object
        :param args: Python default
        :param kwargs: Python default
        """
        Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def validate(self,id_list):
        rv = Form.validate(self)

        if not rv:
            print False
            #Check for the CSRF Token, if it's not there abort.
            return False
        return True
```

or in the application bootstrap:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'myverylongsecretkey'
```

or in the constructor:

```
form = AddToReportForm(secret_key='myverylongsecretkey')
return render_template('random',title='add reports',form=form)
```

Comment: The secret key is set in the configuration file of the application, it works on all forms, except on the ones where I use the SelectField.

Comment: Not entirely sure, since I am still not very well acquainted with Flask ecosystem, but in general it is considered a bad practice to put secret keys directly into source code.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended use:

```
app.secret_key = 'key here' # key user defined
```